# Как посчитать значение производной в определенной точке?

Tags: python, математика, sympy

Пытаюсь найти уравнение касательной в точке к графику функции. Для этого мне нужно вычислить значение производной в точке. Саму производную я могу найти:

```
2*x/(x + 5) - (x**2 - 3)/(x + 5)**2
```

Но вот посчитать ее значение от x0 = 1.9 не знаю как. Как можно это сделать? Вот мой код:

```
x0 = 1.9 
y0 = f(x0)

derivative = sp.diff((x**2 - 3) / (x+5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

воспользуйтесь методом [.evalf()](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html):

```
In [7]: x0 = 1.9

In [8]: y0 = derivative.evalf(subs={x:x0})

In [9]: print(y0)
0.537912203318631
```

PS параметр `subs` ожидает словарь с подстановками значений для `Sympy переменных`. В вашем случае используется переменная `x` - её надо использовать в качестве ключа и значение переменной в качестве значения данного ключа в словаре.

---

Из справки по методу `.evalf()`:

> ```
> subs=<dict>
>     Substitute numerical values for symbols, e.g.
>     subs={x:3, y:1+pi}. The substitutions must be given as a
>     dictionary.
> ```